# Deserializing an array with Gloss

Tags: json, swift

The [Gloss library](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) makes dealing with JSON in Swift much easier. There’s one use case I can’t make out in the docs, however. Suppose you have a key with an array of objects:

```
{
    "id" : 40102424,
    "name": "Gloss",
    "description" : "A shiny JSON parsing library in Swift",
    "html_url" : "https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss",
    "people" : [
        {
            "id" : 5456481,
            "login" : "hkellaway1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 5456482,
            "login" : "hkellaway2"
        },
        {
            "id" : 5456483,
            "login" : "hkellaway3"
        }
    ]
    "language" : "Swift"
}
```

Trying to initialize it like this produces an error:

```
let people : Array<People>?
required init?(json: JSON)
{
    // Error: Value of optional type '[JSON]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    self.people = [People].from(jsonArray: "people" <~~ json)
}
```

What should I be passing in for the “from” function? Force unwrapping the json could cause a crash.

EDIT:

Using a guard statement works, but the "people" key may or may not be included or have zero objects. In that case, the following code would just return nil for the entire object:

```
guard let jarr: [JSON] = "" <~~ json else {
   return nil
}
self.people = [People].from(jsonArray: jarr)
```

Using an if let gives me an error:

```
let people : Array<People>?

// Error: Property 'self.people' not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call
required init?(json:JSON)
{
   if let jarr : [JSON] = "people" <~~ json {
      self.people = [People].from(jsonArray: jarr)
   }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `self.people = []` outside of the `if let` in this case. You need to ensure that `people` has been initialised before the end of the `init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unwrapping the people array from the json before creating the array. The `init` method is failable, so it doesn't matter if you return `nil`.

```
let people: Array<People>?
required init?(json: JSON) {
    guard let people: [JSON] = "people" <~~ json, else {
        return nil
    }
    self.people = [People].from(people)
}
```

EDIT:

```
let people: [People] = []
required init?(json: JSON) {
    if let peopleJSON: [JSON] = "people" <~~ json,
        let people = [People].from(people) {
        self.people = people
    }
}
```

This way `people` will always be at least an empty array and if there are people to add to it, they will be added.

Comment: That works, but what if I want to allow JSON with no people objects? Like if "people" is a key that may or may not appear? In the case of no objects, the initialization would fail. Adding an edit to my question.

Comment: Thanks. That still throws an error though. At the "self.people = " line: Value of optional type '[People]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: See new edit. Now including the generating of the people in the `if let` as it returns an optional value.

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same thing and ask you to add it to your answer. Man. Swift is such a verbose language. Thanks for the help. You can also make people optional, and then just add an else statement that sets it to nil if the unwrapping fails.